# UIView Representative Does Not Conform to Protocol

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to coding and am working on an app to display graphs using XCODE (13.1)/Swift.  I want to be able to swipe to go from graph to graph, but have been unable to get it functioning.  I originally tried to use a class to call for the swipe, but ran into conflicts with the UIView.

I think that the answer is to use a UIViewRepresentative, but I got an error that it did not conform to protocol. Here is the code for the approach using class (I have commented the options out as I have been troubleshooting.

```
/*class SwipeView: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapForSwipe))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapForSwipe))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}
@objc private func tapForSwipe(sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.direction == .right {
       Charttype = Charttype - 1
        print("right")
    }
    
    else if sender.direction == .left {
        Charttype = Charttype + 1
        return
    }
    if Charttype > 16 {
        Charttype = 16
        return
    }
    if Charttype < 0 {
        Charttype = 0
        return
}
```

And here is the code for the UIViewRepresentative approach:

```
enter 
struct swipeGesture : UIViewRepresentable {

    

func makeCoordinator() -> swipeGesture.Coordinator {
    return swipeGesture.Coordinator()
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<swipeGesture>) -> UIView{
    
    let view = UIView()
    let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target :context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.left))
    left.direction = .left
    
    let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(context.coordinator.right))
    right.direction = .right
    
    view.addGestureRecognizer(left)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(right)
    
    return view
}
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<swipeGesture>) {
    
}

class Coordinator : NSObject{
    
    @objc func left(){
        print("left")
        
    }
    @objc func right(){
        print("right")
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help and guidance on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and `UIViewRepresentable`. Your two function calls above need to be:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Self.Context) {
```

and

```
func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {
```

You're using `UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<swipeGesture>` which is not relevant here, and the source of your problems. The error message you're seeing is that `swipeGesture` (should be `SwipeGesture`, by the way, types start with upper case letters) doesn't conform to `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, which is true. The compiler only thinks it should because you've mentioned it in the signature of these two methods.

The wider issue may be why you think this is a solution to your problem. `UIViewRepresentable` is for injecting UIKit views into a SwiftUI app, yet from your question it seems like you're building a UIKit app anyway, so I'm not sure why you're going this route. But that's a different question, I think.